# Downloading files from an external url with PHP

Tags: php, file, url, download, zip

I'm making a website where you can download multiple files at once as a zip file by selecting what files you want to download. And to download the files I want to use an external URL however when the user downloads the zip file to their PC it is completely empty and unable to be opened. I have tried debugging my code but I get no errors.

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['files'])) {
$error = ""; //error holder
if(isset($_POST['createzip'])) {
    $post = $_POST; 
    $tmpFile = tempnam('/tmp', '');
    if(extension_loaded('zip')) { 
    // Checking ZIP extension is available
    if(isset($post['files']) and count($post['files']) > 0) { 
    // Checking files are selected
    $zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library 
    if($zip->open($tmpFile, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) { 
        // Opening zip file to load files
        $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
    }
    foreach($post['files'] as $file) { 
        $context = stream_context_create(
            array(
                "http" => array(
                    "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
                )
            )
        );
        $fileContent = file_get_contents($file, false, $context);

        $zip->addFile(basename($file), $fileContent); // Adding files into zip
        //echo "WORKS"; This part of the code seems to be working.
        //die();
    }
    $zip->close();
    if(file_exists($tmpFile)) {
        // push to download the zip
        header('Content-type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmpFile));
        readfile($tmpFile);
        // remove zip file is exists in temp path
        unlink($tmpFile);
    } else {
        exit("Error finding file.");
    }
}
else
$error .= "* Please select file to zip ";
}
else
$error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension";
}
}
```

Thanks,
Nimetu.

Comment: You seem to be mixing things up when adding files to your zip. You are using `$zip->addFile` however you're passing parameters that are expected for `$zip->addFromString`. You need to either change the function call, or the parameters being passed. See [addFromString](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php) and [addFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) in the docs. I haven't tried running the code, so don't know if there are other issues, but that's what I spotted at first glance.

Comment: I tried adding `$zip->addFromString(basename($file), $fileContent);` but it didn't work. It now shows 1KB as the size which is correct for the image I'm using to test it but when trying to open the ZIP file it says "Can not open file as zip archive".

Comment: `addFromString` returns a boolean for whether it managed to successfully add the file to the zip archive, I'd recommend checking that to make sure it's coming back as true. Only other thing I can suggest is to try accessing the file using `$_FILES` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: I managed to get it working by changing the position of "/" in here `$tmpFile = tempnam('tmp/', '');` (It is now after the "p"). But one problem still remains if I try to download something from an url that ends with `/download?version=364651` for example, meaning that it downloads the file automatically when a user goes to that link. If I attempt to download something from a link like that then there actually isn't a proper JAR file in there that I want to download. There is just a file with the name "download_version=364651".

Comment: Glad this issue is sorted. If you go to the URL by typing it into a browser, it is sent as a GET request, not POST request. That means your code won't get executed, as your initial `if` statement will fail (`$_POST['files']` will not be set). To be able to type in a URL like that, you will need to save the zip files on the server and have some logic to retrieve and return that file when the URL is hit.

Comment: I think you understood me wrong. What I want to do is: A user selects the files they want to download (All of the inputs in the form are assigned a link) then they click submit. Then the server goes to for example https://example.com/thingtodownload/download?version=364651, downloads the file from there, zips it up and serves it to the user. The current code only works for links that don't automatically download the file for some reason.

Comment: I think I understand now. You should create a new question for this issue if you're still having troubles, as it doesn't directly relate to this issue here.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help so far!